# Why are the contents inside the beamerbuttons raised from the baseline asymmetrically?

Tags: beamer, button

In these lockdown days, I am creating my entire lecture note in `beamer` and I use the `beamerbutton` for cross-reference purpose mainly. As a result, I have to place it in the middle of a line. The problem is, it raises the text inside the button asymmetrically, making the entire line look not so appealing. The problem is more noticeable when using the button inside brackets or parenthesis. I realise that creating a padding around a word will need some extra space, but all I want it to be more vertically symmetrically typeset. Following is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    abc \beamerbutton{\scriptsize content} def\\[2ex]
    abc (\beamerbutton{\scriptsize content}) def
\end{document}
```

[image]

**PS:** I usually increase the font size inside the button to `\scriptsize` to make them more conveniently readable. I have observed that it does not change the height of the button.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: It appears that the button "frame" is set on the baseline.  I had thought to "raise" the button (negatively) by the amount defined as the thickness of the "frame"  (which should be able to be determined from the definition of the button), but since you change the font size within the button, @David's approach is probably better.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes my "plan a" was to lower it by \dp\strutbox but subjectively it looked too low so I just set it to what looked right, for me, today, with that text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just adjusted this by eye so it looked reasonable in the parenthesis

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\zzbutton[1]{\sbox0{\beamerbutton{\strut\scriptsize#1}}\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\usebox{0}}}
\begin{document}
    abc \zzbutton{content} def\\[2ex]
    abc (\zzbutton{content}) def
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. What an elegant solution!